# Recover LVM after overwrite with dd

Tags: linux, data-recovery, ext4, dd, lvm

Know that my chances are small (if even there are :().

I have a HDD of 500G with 1 logical volume (ext4). By accident I overwrote it with an ISO of 1,5G:

```
dd if=linuxmint-18-xfce-32bit.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Now I lost all data. Is there some way to re-create the logical volume to get some data back? I have the LVM backup file.

The HDD was used as system disk until 1 month ago. Then I added the boot and swap partition to the logical volume so I presume that `dd` only overwrote the space that was used by these partitions.

Comment: Do you know what partitions order was on that disk before they was destroyed? If the partition with data was started from first sector of the disk you haven't any chance. Another you can try to find lost filesystem via `testdisk` program.

Comment: When it was destroyed there was only 1 partition. A few weeks ago it was partition nbr 3 (`/dev/sdb5`) but I merged them with `parted` into 1 big partition :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not succeed to restore the partition since it missed the start of it. What I did was recovering most of my data with the tool [photorec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec) that is from the same author as `testdisk`. Before I could use it I had to create a partition that started after the `ISO` partition until the end of the disk. `photorec` searched this partition and recovered the 'known to the tool' file types.

The only (small) problem is the fact that the file names are all numeric but with the correct suffix.